# Efficient queries in Directed Acyclic Graph

Tags: python, django, data-structures, directed-acyclic-graphs

I am building a directed acyclic graph (using python/django) with these constraints -

**Graph Constraints** -

1. Self links(Parent == Child) are not allowed.
2. A node can't be it's ancestor.

**Custom Constraints -**

1. A node's child can't be descendant of it's other child(Uncle/aunt relationship not allowed). Though node can be it's cousin (Siblings can have same node as child).
2. Maximum level of any node can be 10 (level = shortest distance of node from root).

**Database -**

1. Table 1 (Node) - id, name
2. Table 2 (Edge) - id, parent_id(fk),
   child_id(fk)

**Validation -** 
I am using [this](https://github.com/elpaso/django-dag) django package for implementing the graph with slight modifications. Here is the validation part -

```
def constraints_checker(parent, child):
    """
    Checks all the constraints
    """
    parent_ancestors = parent.get_ancestors_set()
    if parent == child:
        raise ValidationError('Self links are not allowed.')
    if child in parent_ancestors:
        raise ValidationError('The object is an ancestor.')
    # max level validation
    root_nodes = parent.get_roots()
    for root_node in root_nodes:
        if root_node.longest_distance(parent) >= 10:
            raise ValidationError('Max. 10 levels allowed.')
    # uncle aunt relationship validation
    # 1. parent's children's descendents != node
    parent_children = parent.children.exclude(id=child.id)
    for parent_child in parent_children:
        if child in parent_child.get_descendants_set():
            raise ValidationError('Uncle/aunt relationship not allowed.')
    for ancestor in parent_ancestors:
        # 2. ancestor's child != node
        if child in ancestor.children.all():
            raise ValidationError('Uncle/aunt relationship not allowed.')
```

I am using [recursive functions](https://github.com/elpaso/django-dag/blob/master/django_dag/models.py) as of now to find ancestors and descendents. How can I optimize this graph for faster queries?

[Django mptt tree](https://github.com/django-mptt/django-mptt/) stores left, right flag for faster tree traversal. Can we use something [similar](https://www.sitepoint.com/hierarchical-data-database-2/) for this graph?

**Relevant SO Answer** -

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/1266151/2350219

Comment: There are some funny complications because this is in a DAG, for example a pair of nodes can have more than 1 LCA, and the nodes may be uncle/nephew (from the perspective of one ancestor) and also siblings (from the perspective of an other ancestor) simultaneously. Is that legal? If it is, you can "legalize" uncles by adding a common parent for the offending pair.

Comment: @harold There was a bit confusion. I've edited the question now. Point 1 of custom constraints covers about uncle/aunt relationship. I want to optimize the queries.